# How do I put a login sound in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: sound, login, shutdown

I have Lubuntu 14.04 installed on my machine, but how do I put a custom login sound in it? I prefer the boot sound from old versions like 5.10 & 6.06, are they still in Ubuntu, and how about Lubuntu? If so, how do I enable them? And, can I also put a shutdown sound?